# PHP replacing all occurances of certain string pattern in HTML formatted text

Tags: php, replace

I have input text that can be long HTML text with tags and so on. Example of input can be something like:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur</strong> adipiscing elit.<p>
<p>%image1%</p>
<h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
<p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.</p>
<p>%image2%</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
<p>%image3%</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
...
```

What would be the easiest way of finding all occurrences of text between `%%` characters and replacing that with `<img src="image1.jpg">`?

Comment: Word of warning: `The current trend is 10% in comparison to 5% last year. %graph1%` (Either don't allow a space after % or prepare for some trouble with `<img src=" in comparison to 5.jpg">`

Comment: I don't quite understand this comment? Can you please explain?

Comment: BTW: I can force something else then `%image1%` to users who will use this? Should I use `#iamge1#` or something else instead?

Comment: What I mean, is that if you have a string that contains two of your selection characters, '%' in this case you will select the text in between those characters and might unintentionally add an image where you don't want one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace('|%(.+)%|', '<img src="$1">', $text );
```

working example: http://codepad.org/20Oz3Vok

Comment: Is there a way to replace every occurrence separately? Because I need to see what's the value between %% and then accordingly to this find the right image in DB and put it in...!

Answer (score 1):

try using `preg_replace ('/%(.+?)%/', '<img src="image1.jpg">', $string);` i might be a little bit off on the regex pattern as to rather u need to escape %, and if ? is the greedy symbol.

Comment: -1. Would explode on %image1% text %image2%. It will create only one image.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('|%(\w+)%|', '<img src="$1">', $string);
```

It will only allow alphanumeric characters, as well as underscores (to prevent the problem @AlexanderVarwijk pointed out in the comments).

Comment: of course it will. \w matches alpha**numeric** characters, plus underscores. Thats `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`,